# NodeJS problems with imports when transpiling from typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have implemented simple rest api with `nodejs` and connection to database via `typeorm`. Here are some snippets of code which I wrote:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  Unique,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn
} from "typeorm";
import { Length, IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

@Entity()
@Unique(["username"])
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  @Length(4, 20)
  username: string;
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "lib": [
        "es2015"
    ]
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "node-with-ts",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "dist/app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && node dist/app.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "prod": "node ./dist/app.js",
        "build": "npm install && tsc -p .",
        "reset": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf dist/ && npm run build",
        "migration:run": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
        "@types/node": "^12.7.5",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
        "ts-node": "8.4.1",
        "tslint": "^5.12.1",
        "typescript": "^3.3.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
        "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.4",
        "@types/helmet": "0.0.42",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.1",
        "class-validator": "^0.9.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "4.17.1",
        "helmet": "^3.21.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "sqlite3": "^4.1.0",
        "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.32",
        "typeorm": "^0.2.12"
    }
}
```

I have pasted lots of code because I have no idea what is wrong. I am tryinf to run app via `npm run start` and it throws below error:

```
> tsc && node dist/app.js

    /Users/workspace/node_typescript_project/src/entity/User.ts:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {
                                                                  ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Although I able to build to project and it generates `js` codes but when it comes to run application it throws errors.

Comment: Can you give us your node version ? In a terminal `node -v`. Your issue is that `import` is a ES6 keyword, and your node version seems to not handle this.

Comment: node: v8.9.4
npm: 6.11.3

Comment: Can you show your project folder structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entities are probably not being referenced correctly in your Typeorm config file.

Try to see if you can get it to work with the following ormconfig.js file (pay special attention to the `entities` property:

```js
// ormconfig.js at root of project
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
module.exports = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  port: process.env.MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
  username: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  synchronize: isDevelopment,
  logging: isDevelopment,
  entities: [
    isDevelopment ? `src/**/*.entity.ts` : `dist/**/*.entity.js`,
  ],
  migrations: [`src/migration/**/*.ts`],
  subscribers: ['src/subscriber/**/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src/entity',
    migrationsDir: 'src/migration',
    subscribersDir: 'src/subscriber',
  },
};
```

With this setup, I have ts-node working directly with my Typescript source files, and only in production do I use tsc to build.  When building for prod, I need to reference the .js files inside of the dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to replicate the issue but couldn't replicate it. Just created a sample repo for above code.

https://github.com/pktippa/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/58148222

Comment: Why do you have Babel in your package lock json?

Comment: And which node and npm do you have?

Comment: babel got installed because of tslint requires it and, tslint is a devDependency in the package.json. 

OS: Windows 10 Pro

NodeJs: **8.15.0**

NPM: **6.7.0**

Answer (score 0):

Try a different import syntax, eg.:
 import { bcrypt } from "bcryptjs";

Other import syntax examples can be found [here](https://blog.jdriven.com/2017/06/typescript-and-es6-import-syntax/).

Answer (score 0):

Node.js does not handle ES6 syntax, with imports etc.
For that you have to transpile your ES6 code to ES5, you can do it with Babel => https://github.com/babel/example-node-server

If you don't want to use Babel, you can simply replace `import` by `require`:

```js
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");  // same as 'import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";'
```

Comment: Node only handles es6 when used with mjs files, and the experimental flag turned on.